# Google Places API nearest place phone number

Tags: java, android

May I know how to get phone number from the google places API?

I need to display name of the place including the phone number. Now I am able to get the name, but not the phone number.

Comment: Should be able to just use place.getPhonenumber() if the place has a valid number.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place.html#public-methods

Answer (score 0):

```
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.731212, 76.830220);        

var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng,
            zoom: 12,
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);      


 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
     service.nearbySearch(request, callback);

var request = { 
                    location: myLatlng,
                    radius: '20000',
                    types: ['atm' , 'hospital',  'resturant', 'accounting', 'airport', 'food', 'bank', 'park']
                  };  

    function callback(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  var place = results[i];
console.log(place);
                   console.log(place.phone_number);
                }
              }
            }
```

In Place object you got every place details. Check you console and if phone number exists then it will return in **place.phone** or **place.phone_number**. Please check the actual key for phone number.

Comment: i use  poi.setPhone(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("phone", " "));

Comment: but,,the result is no phone number.